# Data being fetched two times when using React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am in the process of attaching my React frontend to my node express backend. The backend api is working fine. The React frontend with a fake data file is working fine. Now I'm trying to use React Redux and createAsyncThunk and createSlice to fetch data from the backend api.

My problem is that the data is being fetched two times. Specifically, I'm trying to fetch information on 10 donors. But I get an array of 20 donors (the same 10 donors twice.)

Please explain why and how I can fix it.

My donorSlice.js code is here:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Donors } from '../components/Donors';
import { client } from './client';

const initialState = {
    donors: [],
    status: 'idle',
    error: null
}

export const fetchLast10Donors = createAsyncThunk('donors/fetchLast10Donors', async () => {
    const response = await client.get('http://localhost:5000/getLast10Donors')
    //api works fine. Checked with Postman
    return response.data
});


export const donorSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'donors',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        //not using the reducers; only using extraReducers
         createDonor: (state, action) => {
            state.donors.push(action.payload)
        },
        editDonor: (state, action) => {
            const newDonorList = state.donors.map(donor => {
                if (donor.auto_id === action.payload.auto_id) {
                    return action.payload;
                } else {
                    return donor;
                }
            });
            state.donors = newDonorList;
        },
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchLast10Donors.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'loading'
            })
            .addCase(fetchLast10Donors.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'succeeded'
                state.donors = state.donors.concat(action.payload)
            })
            .addCase(fetchLast10Donors.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'failed'
                state.error = action.error.message
            })
    }
});

export const { createDonor, editDonor } = donorSlice.actions;

export default donorSlice.reducer;
```

My MainComponent.js looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import GiftDisplay from './GiftDisplayComponent';
import DonorDisplay from "./DonorDisplayComponent";
import DonorGiftTest from './DonorGiftTableTestComponent';
import { Routes, Route, Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { createDonor, editDonor, fetchLast10Donors } from "../app/donorSlice";

const Main = (props) => {


    const donors = useSelector((state) => state.donors.donors);
    console.log(donors);
    const gifts = useSelector((state) => state.gifts.gifts);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const donorStatus = useSelector(state => state.donors.status);
    console.log(donorStatus);
    const error = useSelector(state => state.donors.error);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (donorStatus === 'idle') {
            dispatch(fetchLast10Donors())
        }
    }, [donorStatus, dispatch]);

    const handleDonorCreate = (values) => {
        dispatch(createDonor(values))
    };

    const handleDonorEdit = (values) => {
        dispatch(editDonor(values))
    };

    const handleHistoryClick = (donorId) => {
        console.log('MainComponent history click id is ' + donorId);
        const donor = donors.find(donor => (
            donorId === donor.auto_id
        ));
        console.log(donor.lastname);
    };

    const Navigation = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav
                    style={{
                        borderBottom: 'solid 1px',
                        paddingBottom: '1rem',
                    }}
                    >
                    <Link to="/donors">Donors</Link> | {" "}
                    <Link to="/gifts">Gifts</Link>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, {props.name}, this is the main component.</h1>
                <hr></hr>
                <Navigation />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Outlet />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={
                            <DonorDisplay 
                            donors={donors}
                            //onFormSubmit={handleDonorCreate}
                            //onDonorEditFormSubmit={handleDonorEdit}
                            //onHistoryClick={handleHistoryClick}
                            />}
                        />
                        <Route path="gifts" element={
                            <GiftDisplay 
                                gifts={gifts}
                                donorId={null}
                            />}
                        />
                        <Route exact path="donors" element={
                            <DonorDisplay 
                                donors={donors}
                                onFormSubmit={handleDonorCreate}
                                onDonorEditFormSubmit={handleDonorEdit}
                                onHistoryClick={handleHistoryClick}
                            />}
                        />
                        <Route path="donors/:donorId" element={<DonorGiftTest />} />
                        <Route path="*" element={
                            <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
                                <p>There's nothing here!</p>
                            </main>}
                        />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};


export default Main;
```

Here is my console log.

```
[] MainComponent.js:15 
MainComponent.js:20 idle
VM77:249 
VM77:249 idle
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <table>.
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5400:5
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6028:85
    at CreateDonor (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:665:78)
    at table
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5400:5
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8429:85
    at DonorTable (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1625:22)
    at div
    at DonorDisplay (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1104:21)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63953:5)
    at div
    at div
    at Main (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2663:74)
    at div
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63886:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62695:5)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60019:5)

MainComponent.js:15 []length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
MainComponent.js:20 loading
react_devtools_backend.js:4029 
react_devtools_backend.js:4029 loading
MainComponent.js:15 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
MainComponent.js:20 succeeded
react_devtools_backend.js:4029 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
react_devtools_backend.js:4029 succeeded
MainComponent.js:15 (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
MainComponent.js:20 succeeded
react_devtools_backend.js:4029 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
react_devtools_backend.js:4029 succeeded
```

Comment: Are you using react18 and `React.StrictMode`? If so, then remove `StrictMode` and see if it helps.

Comment: I am using React 18. I wasn't using ```React.StrictMode```

Comment: Hey There so do you want this request to run this request when dispatch changes  ? try removing dispatch and donorStatus from the dependancy array and let me know if this still occurs other wise make sure to add all the places you invoke the fetchLast10Donors

Comment: I had tried to remove ```dispatch``` and ```donorStatus``` from the useEffect dependency array. The fetching twice and concat still happens. Also, I'm only calling ```fetchLast10Donors()``` once.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have `<React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode>` in index.js. Or something like that.

The problem is that in development mode react mount component twice. The problem with Redux is that `state.status = 'loading'` calls after react mounts component a second time & calls `dispatch(fetchLast10Donors())` for the second time.
So if you would write something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log( donorStatus );
}, [donorStatus]);
```

You wil se in console something like this:

```
idle
idle
loading
succeeded
```

So the possible solution can be useRef (something like this):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import GiftDisplay from './GiftDisplayComponent';
import DonorDisplay from "./DonorDisplayComponent";
import DonorGiftTest from './DonorGiftTableTestComponent';
import { Routes, Route, Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { createDonor, editDonor, fetchLast10Donors } from "../app/donorSlice";

const Main = (props) => {

  const isFetcing = useRef( false );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const donors = useSelector((state) => state.donors.donors);
  const gifts = useSelector((state) => state.gifts.gifts);

  const donorStatus = useSelector(state => state.donors.status);
  const error = useSelector(state => state.donors.error);

  useEffect(() => {
      if ( !isFetcing.current ) {
          dispatch(fetchLast10Donors())
          isFetcing.current = true
      }
  }, [donorStatus, dispatch]);

  // Check if fetch is finished with succes or error status.
  useEffect(() => {
    if ( donorStatus === 'succeeded' || donorStatus === 'error' ) isFetcing.current = false
}, [donorStatus]);
...
```

So you will set isFetching status right after dispatch & won't let start another fetching before donorStatus will have good or bad fetching result.

But as for me I came to conclusion (in similar tutorial code),that it's better to leave everything as it is, just change code in donorSlice.js at success to:

```
.addCase(fetchLast10Donors.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'succeeded'
                state.donors = action.payload
            })
```

So you won't have a bug with `state.donors.concat`.

In case of Redux tutor I made something like this:

```
.addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'succeeded'
    state.donors = action.payload.map( post => { 
        // Some stuff goes here... 
        return post
    } )
})
```

Maybe this will help someone.

P.S. Why they using `concat` in that place? I don't get it. I case of fetching goes twice before ending you will get unreal sh*t in a result...